# Heroku buildpack error while pushing

Tags: python, github, heroku

When i try to add my github repo [Gitlink](https://github.com/EpicShardGamingYT/pymusic) i get this error

```
 !     No default language could be detected for this app.
        HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     Push failed
```

What is wrong???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku: No default language could be detected for this app for python even with runtime.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232967/heroku-no-default-language-could-be-detected-for-this-app-for-python-even-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Heroku knows that your app is a Python app by the existence of one of two files in the root of your application:
>
> - PipFile
> - requirements.txt

You should set up a `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` in order to get your project work on Heroku. In addition, you will need **Postgres** as your deployment DB, *if you need a db at all*.

You can have a look for more at the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#expected-files-for-python) or the [getting started guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction)